# Inject argument externally and dynamically minified js

Tags: javascript, babeljs

In my node js code, I used `babel-minify` for creating minified version. Now that minified file my client using in his code. In my node js app, there is a dropdown so I put static data into it. That dropdown data must be dynamic. Initially, the changes value dropdown using HTML using dropdown ID but those value does not change with original static data.

[image]

I want to he should inject dropdown values dynamically in minified js script so I can reload my dropdown using updated values. How I inject values externally in minified js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found the solution. Binding a function with the `window` object and pass my argument in it.
My HTML file code,

```
 <script src="myMinified.js"></script>
  <script>
    //Call initial method in minified js
    window.initializeALL();
    var dropdownJson = [ { value: 0, name: 'Select' }, {value: 1, name: 'Abc' }, { value: 2, name: 'Abc1'}, { value: 3, name: 'Abc2' }, { value: 4, name: 'Abc3' }];
    window.passdropdownarg(dropdownJson);
  </script>
```

My JS implementation which minified later using `babel-minify`.

```
//Method call from external HTML script
window.connectorDd = function(dropdownJson){
  externalDropdownValue = dropdownJson || {};
}
```